# Sitecore and Identity Server 3 - Roles missing for authenticated users

Tags: sitecore, identityserver3, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, sitecore9

I am trying to integrate a federated authentication / single sign on with Sitecore using Identity Server 3. Please note that I am not using Azure Active Directory in any way.

I've been following these pages:
http://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/

and

https://dhalgara.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-integrating-azure-ad-along-with-identity-server-3/

I believe I am close, as I'm able to set the login button to appear that takes me away to the Identity Server for authentication. I then enter in a username/password, and then it properly authenticates and redirects me back to the Sitecore login page with the following error:

**You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator.**

I confirmed that I am authenticating and that when I go to the user management screen in Sitecore, I find some users with funny names that must have been created via the login process I mentioned. They are also not a part of any roles, which is why I suspect I can't log in.

Almost all the sites mention configuring this block of XML is key:

```
<transformation type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
  <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
    <claim name="x" value="y" />
  </sources>
  <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
    <claim name="something here" value="Sitecore\Developer" />
  </targets>
  <keepSource>true</keepSource>
</transformation>
```

But what does this really mean? I inspected my JWT and I don't have any claims coming back such as "roles" or "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", but is that even necessary to assign a developer role to my user? What should be in the X/Y values above, and what should the value of "something here" be so that my user is made a Sitecore\Developer role (or some other role that I want)?

**How can I ensure that when my user is signed in, I can put them as part of a particular group?**

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting below error, it means there is something wrong in the app configuration on Identity Server, check the configuration it could be Redirect url or Site Host name.

```
You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator.
```

RECOMMENDED: Revisit your App configuration in the Identity Server / Azure AD.

The block you mentioned is basically to set the Role permission for the user. The below configuration will allow you to set  the default claims for Sitecore/Developer Role.

```
<transformation name="Transform to Sitecore DEV Role" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="groups" value="<GUID>" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name=__"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Sitecore\Developer" />
                <claim name="__http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Sitecore\Author" />
                <claim name="__http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="sitecore\Analytics Personalization" />
                <claim name="__http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="sitecore\Analytics Maintaining" />
                <claim name="__http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="sitecore\Forms Editor" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
```

If you are seeing funny names get added to Sitecore, then try the solution recommended in the Sitecore community in the below link.

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/8801